# Serialized data being displayed

Tags: php, html, forms, serialization

I need to make a config file for my application, but i stumbled upon a problem, i tried to solve it but couldn't find the problem, the code here works, except for one thing, whenever i submit the form, it will save the data, but when it reloads it will just show the serialized data stored in config.txt.

Does anyone know why this happens and how i can solve it

Thanks for your help
-oedze

edit: to explain more clearly:
The idee is that the data stored in config.txt will all be inputed in the form, so you dont have to constantly add it, and you can see what the values are. when you press the submit button, the page will save all the data in the $config array, after that it will save it in config.txt, when that is done, it will reload the page, so the post data will be removed from the users cache. But, whenever the page reloads, it's showing something like a:1:{s:9:"groupname";s:4:"test";} instead of the html page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <?php
        function getConfig(){
            $file = fopen("config.txt", "r");
            $fileData = fread($file, filesize("config.txt"));
            fclose($file);
            $config = unserialize($fileData);

            return $config;
        }

        function saveConfig($config){
            $file = fopen("config.php", "w");
            fwrite($file, serialize($config));
            fclose($file);
        }
        if(isset($_GET["updateConfig"])){
            $config = array();
            foreach($_POST as $key => $value){
                $config[$key] = $value;
            }
            saveConfig($config);
            header("Location: config.php");
        }else{
            $config = getConfig();
        }



    ?>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Configuratie</h1>
    <form method="post" action="config.php?updateConfig">
    <table>
        <tr class="optionsRow"><td class="optionsData">Groupname:</td><td class="optionsData"><input type="text" name="groupname" value="<?php $config["groupname"]?>"></td></tr>   

    </table>
    <input type="Submit" value="Opslaan">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Whenever i press the submit button, the page will reload, the data will be saved, but then it will show the serialized data instead of the reloaded page, my question is why this happens and how i can solve it

Comment: Since all your code is in one file so remove action attribute from your file. thanks

Comment: @anantkumarsingh Where is the connection to the question? Also, I'd say this is irrelevant.

Comment: _it will show the serialized data instead of the reloaded page_ - Sorry, I still can not figure out the problem. Could you explain more clearly?

Comment: I'd say since you have only a single "group" (only one input), then where is the difference between serialized and unserialized data? It is a string!

Comment: It's gonna have more options, i just got stuck making the first one

Comment: But where you see the serialized string in your page? In the inputbox?

Comment: Everthing on the page is wiped out and replaced with the serialized data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a mistake on this line : `$file = fopen("config.php", "w");`, this is `config.txt` and not `config.php`.